# Variables in bash script in sshexec from ant

Tags: ant

I have a problem with variables in sshexec task.
My build.xml ant script looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="sshexecproject" basedir="." default="build">
<target name="build">
    <sshexec 
        host="192.168.2.106" 
        username="root" 
        password="xxx" 
        commandResource="${basedir}/to_run.sh" 
        trust="true"
        verbose="true"
        failonerror="true"
    />
</target>
```

In the to_run script I have two variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="Pink Panther"
export name2="Panther Pink"

echo "Name: "
echo $name
echo "Name with export: "
echo $name2
```

If I run the script on terminal i get the following output:

```
$ ./to_run.sh 
Name: 
Pink Panther
Name with export: 
Panther Pink
```

We can see that all works fine. But if I start the build.xml script from ant i get the following output:

```
...
[sshexec] Authentication succeeded (password).
[sshexec] cmd : #!/bin/bash
[sshexec] cmd : 
[sshexec] cmd : name="Pink Panther"
[sshexec] cmd : export name2="Panther Pink"
[sshexec] cmd : 
[sshexec] cmd : echo "Name: "
[sshexec] Name: 
[sshexec] cmd : echo $name
[sshexec] 
[sshexec] cmd : echo "Name with export: "
[sshexec] Name with export: 
[sshexec] cmd : echo $name2
[sshexec] 
[sshexec] Disconnecting from ...
```

We can see that on the remote server this script create an empty echo. The variable name and name2 is not filled. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing this line:

```
commandResource="${basedir}/to_run.sh"
```

to

```
command="${basedir}/to_run.sh"
```

results in the following:

```
[sshexec] Authentication succeeded (password).
[sshexec] cmd : /data/tmp/anttest/to_run.sh
[sshexec] Name:
[sshexec] Pink Panther
[sshexec] Name with export:
[sshexec] Panther Pink
```

`commandResource` takes a resource file with a list of commands and executes each line individually with `bash -c $LINE` so any variables defined are only valid on the same line. `command` executes the whole script in the same shell.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've updated my question, because the problem is still not resolved.

Comment: After further research, `commandResource` is a file of commands, each line of which is executed as `bash -c $LINE`, so each command has a separate shell and context. What you want instead is `command` which will execute the whole script at once.

Comment: If I change commandResource to command I get a file not found error. The script must first on the server before I can use it?

Comment: It looks like that the command is executed on the server side, so the script needs first to be transferred to the server with scp, right?

Comment: That's right, the command has to be a valid command on the server.