# Linux : How to add a Dir location as one the argument in SSHEXEC command

Tags: linux, maven, ant

Im using a MAVEN commands in my ANT scripst in the Linux mechine ,

here is my ant script which calls maven.sh file to clean and install 
sshexec host="**" username="" password="" .... command="/var/-----/mavenBuild.sh/"/>

mavenBuild.sh has : MVN clean install with all the required classpath and maven path loaded in it

but the problem is I have to run this  mavenBuild.sh under a specific dircetory where the POM.xml is located , since i am not mentioning the path of my POM.xml file in the SSHEXEC , the installation is not failling with an error as no pom file exist, IF i run this mavenBuild.sh file manually under by to the location its woring fine . Kindly please help how can i append this location(Directory location of my pom ) in the SSHEXEC as one of the argumensts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven supports the "-f " parameter.

So if you include this parameter in your commandline in mavenBuild.sh, it will work without changing directories

```
mvn -f <path to pom> <goals>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very technical solution and I haven't used SSHEXEC or Maven but couldn't you add a the following to the top of the mavenBuild.sh file?

```
PATHTOXML=/path/to/xml
cd $PATHTOXML
```

or even shorter:

```
cd /path/to/xml
```

You could also pass it as a variable to the mavenBuild.sh if the directory changes.

Moving to the SSHEXEC have you looked at this post, it maybe helpful:
[Variables in bash script in sshexec from ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063194/variables-in-bash-script-in-sshexec-from-ant)

Edit - I can't comment yet :(

Edit again -> I had a thought, i've read you cannot cd with SSHEXEC so is it worth considering  putting the commands in another "install.sh" file and using scp to the remove machine and then SSHEXEC commandresource to execute it

Comment: Hi dear , Thanks a lot it worked by adding in the mavenBuild.sh file , you saved my time many thanks

Comment: No worries, it isn't exactly a great solution but will do as a work around.  I just edited my post and it seems SSHEXEC doesn't allow directory changes so you would need to do it via another method.  I think my original suggestion is the quickest/easiest but perhaps not the most comprehensive.  Good luck. Don't forget to mark as answered etc.  Someone else maybe able to offer a more robust solution.

Comment: I have one more question here can i use exec cmd in linux without using shell script ?